# How to make configuration settings part of Strategy in python-hypothesis

Tags: python, testing

I want to write a test for a method using the hypothesis library.

Within the method, I import configuration settings that differ according to the job that I'm running the codebase for (each unique run of the code gets different settings).

The methods look something like this

Module `user_settings`:

```
setting1 = 5
setting2 = 10
setting3 = -0.085
```

`test_class`

```
import user_settings
import numpy as np

class TestClass():
   def __init__(self):
      self.arr = np.random.normal(size=(5,1))

   def dummy_method(self):
      setting1 = user_settings.setting1
      setting2 = user_settings.setting2
      setting3 = user_settings.setting3

   
      return (self.arr * setting1 + setting2) / setting3
```

I can define the object to feed to this function as a fixture in `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest
from test_class import TestClass

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def test_obj():
   return TestClass()
```

And then incorporate that into the test:

```
def test_dummy_method(test_obj):
    res = test_obj.dummy_method()
    assert np.all(~np.isnan(res))
```

I want to leverage the hypothesis framework to test the output with different settings.  But since they're set within the function, what can I do to make them part of a hypothesis strategy?  I understand that one option is modifying the method to pass those settings as arguments. However, the current architecture was a deliberate design decision to keep the code succinct and clear - there are hundreds of these settings and there was no need up to now to have them as arguments, with the associated clutter (more lines in functions definition plus many more lines from docstrings).

#### Update after comment by Zac Hatfield-Dodds

I can use a context manager to temporarily set different values for the user settings:

```
class SettingContextManager:
    def __enter__(self):
        # Save original settings
        self.original_setting1 = user_settings.setting1
        self.original_setting2 = user_settings.setting2
        self.original_setting3 = user_settings.setting3

        # Patch settings with test values
        user_settings.setting1 = 5
        user_settings.setting2 = -2
        user_settings.setting3 = 99.8

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        # Restore original settings
        user_settings.setting1 = self.original_setting1
        user_settings.setting2 = self.original_setting2
        user_settings.setting3 = self.original_setting3
```

And then use this ContextManager within the dummy method:

```
import numpy as np

def test_dummy_method(test_obj):
    with SettingContextManager():
        res = test_obj.dummy_method()
        assert np.all(~np.isnan(res))
```

Would I then pass the Hypothesis values with a decorator when defining `SettingContextManager` such as like this:

```
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.extra.numpy import floating_dtypes

@given(setting1 = floating_dtypes())
class SettingContextManager:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.original_setting1 = user_settings.setting1
        self.original_setting2 = user_settings.setting2
        self.original_setting3 = user_settings.setting3

        # Patch settings with test values
        user_settings.setting1 = setting1
```

#### Update #2 after follow-up comment by Zac Hatfield-Dodds

I created a reproducible example following Zac's second comment.  It's not erroring when I run `pytest`, but also not sure about the yield component and whether I need an `as` statement where I open the context manager.

Here is the hierarchy of files

```
└───src
    │   dummy_class.py
    │   user_settings.py
    │
    tests
    │   conftest.py
    │   context_manager.py
    │   test_dummy_class.py
```

**Files**

`dummy_class`:

```py
import user_settings
import numpy as np

class TestClass():
   def __init__(self):
      self.arr = np.random.normal(size=(5,1))

   def dummy_method(self):
      setting1 = user_settings.setting1
      setting2 = user_settings.setting2
      setting3 = user_settings.setting3


      return (self.arr * setting1 + setting2) / setting3
```

`user_settings`

```py
setting1 = 5
setting2 = 10
setting3 = -0.085
```

`conftest`

```
import pytest

import sys
sys.path.append('./src')
from dummy_class import TestClass

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def test_obj():
    return TestClass()
```

`context_manager`

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

import user_settings

@contextmanager
def temp_user_setting(new_value):
    # Get the current value of the user_setting
    original_value = user_settings.setting1

    # Set the user_setting to the new value
    user_settings.setting1 = new_value

    try:
        # Yield to allow the test code to execute with the modified user_setting
        yield
    finally:
        # Revert the user_setting back to its original value
        user_settings.setting1 = original_value
```

`test_dummy_class`

```
import numpy as np
from hypothesis import given
import hypothesis.strategies as st

from context_manager import temp_user_setting

@given(st.floats(min_value=0.0, max_value=100.0))
def test_dummy_method(test_obj, setting1):
    with temp_user_setting(setting1):
        res = test_obj.dummy_method()
        assert np.all(~np.isnan(res))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your options are basically:

- refactor your code to accept a config object as an argument, or
- write a context manager `with temp_context(test_obj): dummy_method()` which patches and restores the module-level state to call inside your test function, or
- something equivalent (e.g. `contextvars`)

FWIW it's also not a Hypothesis-specific concern; you'd run into the same problem with e.g. `@pytest.mark.parametrize(...)`, or manually calling it twice, etc.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, only the refactoring option would allow me to leverage Hypothesis' capabilities of automatically trying different values for the parameters.  For both the context manager and `contextVars`, I'd need to manually specify different settings.  Is this right?

Comment: No, you could still create the settings object using Hypothesis.  At this point I think you need to provide a minimal but _complete_ working example.

Comment: Added to original question, please let me know if that's enough.

Comment: No, I still can't run that code.

Comment: I added a complete reproducible example, please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Yep, `Update #2` is exactly what I was thinking of.  Doing `yield foo` means that `with f() as x:` will set `x = foo`; in this case you don't need to do that because you already have the `new_value` available if you wanted it.

Comment: Great, thank you!  Removed yielding the settings and just left yield.